# Entity Framework + sql injection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-injection

I'm building up an `IQueryable` where I am applying relevant filters, and I come across this line of code here.

```
items = items.OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sortBy, sortDirection));
```

Is this snippet vulnerable to SQL injection? Or are these (string) parameters parameterized behind the scenes? I assumed that all Linq queries were escaped and parameterized for me, but the fact that I am able to pass in a string directly like this is throwing me off.

Comment: Does that statement work for you?  Do you have a static extension method implementing it?  I'm not familiar with `OrderBy` not taking a lamba expression.

Comment: This extension was located in the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace.
with a method signature `static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values)`.

Comment: Looks like System.Linq.Dynamic is an open-source project hosted on CodePlex. The source code is at http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DynamicLinq/System.Linq.Dynamic/Dynamic.cs. From what I can see they are taking the string data and using it to modify the expression tree so, no, it's not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## First Point :

You have to avoid returning `IQueryable<T>` types from methods that are exposed to potentially untrusted callers for the **following reasons:**

- A consumer of a query that exposes an `IQueryable<T>` type could call
  methods on the result that expose secure data or increase the size of
  the result set. *For example,* consider the following method signature:

  `public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerId)`

A consumer of this query could call `.Include("Orders")` on the returned `IQueryable<Customer>` to retrieve data that the query did not intend to expose. This can be avoided by changing the return type of the method to `IEnumerable<T>` and calling a method (such as `.ToList()`) that materializes the results.

- Because `IQueryable<T>` queries are executed when the results are
  iterated over, a consumer of a query that exposes an `IQueryable<T>`
  type could catch exceptions that are thrown. `Exceptions` could contain
  information not intended for the consumer.

## Second Point :

**How to prevent SQL injection attacks ?**

- **Entity SQL injection attacks:**

SQL injection attacks can be performed in Entity SQL by supplying `malicious input` to values that are used in a `query predicate` and in `parameter names`.

***To avoid*** the risk of SQL injection

> you should never combine user input with Entity SQL command text

Entity SQL queries `accept parameters` everywhere that literals are accepted. ***You should use parameterized queries instead of injecting literals*** from an external agent directly into the query. You should also consider ***using query builder methods*** to safely construct Entity SQL.

- **LINQ to Entities injection attacks:**

Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries, LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation or concatenation, and ***they are not susceptible to traditional SQL injection attacks.***

**Reference :** [**Security Considerations (Entity Framework)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760(v=vs.110).aspx)